# Why does Java muti-threaded code deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

The complete code for this question is available here:
https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/thread-tool

The code shown below seems to run to completion but never escapes the while loop shown here.

```
    while (this.active.size() > 0) {
        // System.out.println("here");
    }
```

If I uncomment the `// System.out.println("here");` it does run to completion.  It also runs to completion if I add a sleep-for-one-second.

The larger problem is that if I try to use this code in a real application the code runs for awhile and then seems to deadlock (i.e. the code just stops running).

What do I need to do to fix this?

```
package org.nachc.tools.threadtool;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.nachc.tools.threadtool.runnableiter.ThreadToolUser;
import org.nachc.tools.threadtool.worker.ThreadToolWorker;
import org.nachc.tools.threadtool.worker.ThreadToolWorkerRunnable;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ThreadRunner {

    private int numberOfThreadsPerWorker;

    private int numberOfRunnablesPerWorker;

    private int numberOfWorkers;

    private ThreadToolUser runnableIter;

    private List<ThreadToolWorker> active = new ArrayList<ThreadToolWorker>();

    private Object lock = new Object();

    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public ThreadRunner(int numberOfThreadsPerWorker, int numberOfRunnablesPerWorker, int numberOfWorkers, ThreadToolUser runnableIter) {
        this.numberOfThreadsPerWorker = numberOfThreadsPerWorker;
        this.numberOfRunnablesPerWorker = numberOfRunnablesPerWorker;
        this.numberOfWorkers = numberOfWorkers;
        this.runnableIter = runnableIter;
        this.executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfWorkers);
    }

    public void exec() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            addWorkers();
        }
        while (this.active.size() > 0) {
            // System.out.println("here");
        }
        log.info("SHUTTING DOWN----------------");
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw (new RuntimeException(exp));
        }
    }

    private void addWorkers() {
        log.info("start addWorkers");
        while (runnableIter.hasNext() && active.size() < numberOfWorkers) {
            ThreadToolWorker worker = getNextWorker();
            if (worker == null) {
                break;
            } else {
                this.active.add(worker);
            }
        }
        log.info("done addWorkers");
    }

    private ThreadToolWorker getNextWorker() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            log.info("start next worker");
            if (runnableIter.hasNext() == false) {
                return null;
            }
            List<Runnable> runnableList = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
            while (runnableList.size() < numberOfRunnablesPerWorker && runnableIter.hasNext()) {
                runnableList.add(runnableIter.getNext());
            }
            ThreadToolWorker worker = new ThreadToolWorker(runnableList, numberOfThreadsPerWorker, this);
            ThreadToolWorkerRunnable runnable = new ThreadToolWorkerRunnable(worker);
            this.executor.execute(runnable);
            log.info("done next worker");
            return worker;
        }
    }

    public void done(ThreadToolWorker worker) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            log.info("start done");
            this.active.remove(worker);
            if (active.size() > 0) {
                addWorkers();
            }
            log.info("done done");
        }
    }

    public void logActive() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            log.info("------------");
            log.info("active:  " + active.size());
            log.info("waiting: " + runnableIter.waiting());
            log.info("------------");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a deadlock, since no locks are involved.   (In fact, it is the absence of locking that is probably causing the problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop accesses `this.active.size()` without any synchronization. Java's [*memory visibility rules*](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/Concurrency%2C+Visibility%2C+and+Memory) do not guarantee when (if *ever*) one thread that looks at shared variables will see changes made by other threads if the thread that's looking does not use some form of synchronization with the other threads.

---

If you want to [*poll*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) the state of the `active` list, then consider doing something like this:

```java
while (true) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        if (this.active.size() <= 0) break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `sleep()` call gives other threads a chance to run. Without the sleep, the thread that's running this loop will use 100% of a CPU, which may be detrimental to the performance of your application.

---

But there are better options than polling. You could do this to wait until the `active` list becomes empty.

```java
synchronized(lock) {
    while (this.active.size() > 0) {
        lock.wait();
    }
}
```

The [`wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) call temporarily releases the `lock`, then it waits for another thread to [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) the lock, and finally, it re-locks the lock before it returns:

```java
public void done(ThreadToolWorker worker) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        log.info("start done");
        this.active.remove(worker);
        if (active.size() > 0) {
            addWorkers();
        }
        else {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
        log.info("done done");
    }
}
```